# SQL aggregated groups

Tags: mysql, sql, grouping

I feel like this is a stupid question, but I haven't been able to find a solution by searching. I have a dataset with sales data, where I want to group some of the ID groups together and show the sum of sales. I'm not concerned with individual items, I want to see only the groups of items and the sum of their sales.

A simplified version of what I'm doing now is:

```
SELECT year, quarter, company, segment, sum(sales) AS total_sales
FROM table
WHERE segment = 001 OR segment = 015
AND producer LIKE '%ACME Inc.%'
AND year = 2015 OR year = 2016
GROUP BY quarter, year, producer, segment
ORDER BY year, quarter, producer, segment ASC
;
```

My main problem is getting segments 001 and 015 into the same group, for instance 'Jelly' so that the output shows

```
year|quarter|company|segment|total_sales

2015|1|ACME Inc.|Jelly|100
```

where 'Jelly' includes both segments 001 and 015.

I'm able to list alle the individual items, but not group them up with in aggregated groups. My problem is being able to filter only the companies I want to look at, and only the segments I want to look at, at the same time as I'm creating and listing custom groups of the segments.

Thanks for any help :)

Edit: MCVE here - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2414bd/3

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`company` text, `sales` int, `year` int, `quarter` int,
     `segment` text)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`year`, `quarter`, `company`, `segment`, `sales`)
VALUES
    (2015,1,'ACME',001,100),
    (2015,1,'ACME',015,100),
    (2015,1,'HAL',001,25),
    (2015,1,'HAL',015,25),
    (2015,1,'ACME',002,50),
    (2015,1,'HAL',003,50)
/*many other companies and segments as well*/
;
```

Comment: Thanks, I've created a MCVE here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2414bd/3 :)

Comment: What I'd want is to group up the two 100-sales to 200, and thus only having one row with 200 instad of two rows of 100 each for ACME and jelly for instance.

Comment: I see - MySQL is just confusing the segment aliases - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2414bd/8

Comment: Thanks, that's it! Is there a way to upvote an edit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT year, quarter, company,
CASE
  WHEN segment IN (001,015)
  THEN 'Jelly'
  WHEN segment IN (002,003)
  THEN 'Bread' ELSE segment END segment,
SUM(sales) AS total_sales
FROM Table1
WHERE company LIKE '%ACME%' OR company LIKE '%HAL%'
AND year IN (2015,2016)
GROUP 
   BY year
    , quarter
    , company
    , CASE WHEN segment IN (001,015) THEN 'Jelly'
           WHEN segment IN (002,003) THEN 'Bread' 
           ELSE segment
           END
 ORDER 
    BY year, quarter, company, segment ASC
;
```

Comment: I am running into a different problem now, though. There is a lot of data that isn't wanted in my query, but it is still included: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d1fa78/1 In the first row I get an unwanted result.

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: What I mean is - I'd prefer to not have the first row show up as it's not part of the newsegments.

Answer (score 1):

First, I think you need to fix your `where` clause.  Numbers that start with `0` are usually strings.  Plus, you should be using `in` and careful about the `and`/`or` logic:

```
SELECT year, quarter, company, segment, sum(sales) AS total_sales
FROM table
WHERE segment IN ('001', '015') AND
      producer LIKE '%ACME Inc.%' AND
      year IN (2015, 2016)
GROUP BY quarter, year, producer, segment
ORDER BY year, quarter, producer, segment ASC;
```

Next, if you want to combine segments, use `case`.  You seem to want:

```
SELECT year, quarter, company, 'Jelly' as segement,
       SUM(sales) AS total_sales
FROM table
WHERE segment IN ('001', '015') AND
      producer LIKE '%ACME Inc.%' AND
      year IN (2015, 2016)
GROUP BY quarter, year, producer
ORDER BY year, quarter, producer ASC;
```

Comment: Thanks for the notes about using IN. If I set 'Jelly' as segment, it will be set for all segments, but I need to be able to differentiate between several segments, not only jelly, but others as well.